# How to sync data insight API with bitcored?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, bitcore

I am using bitcoin-node-api module of nodejs for that I am running bitcored and

start my server which runs fine.

I have transfered money from blockchain wallet to address generated by bitcored successfully.But it not showing me balance on http://localhost:3000/insight/ site.

My question is,how to sync bitcored with http://localhost:3000/insight/ ?

I have tried bitcored INSIGHT_FORCE_RPC_SYNC=1 but still no luck ( When I open status it looks like->,

[dashboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcGz7.png)